# NodeJS ADFS integration using Passport-SAML

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, passport.js, adfs

I am trying to integrate my NodeJS, Express and PassportJS application with ADFS for the single sign-on using [bergie/passport-saml](https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml/blob/master/docs/adfs/README.md).

As part of the 'Create Relying Party' step, I have generated this XML.

```
<EntityDescriptor entityID="my-app" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>MIICvDCCAaQC...<truncated for brevity>...Mbz0=</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://testapp.my-company.com/my-app/logout"/>
    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://testapp.my-company.com/my-app/authenticated" index="0"/>
  </SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

Our IT team handling ADFS side of things is advising me that this XML may not be correct ( for ex: it does not have the fully qualified domain name of my app testapp.my-company.com). 
Please can someone suggest me if the above relaying party XML correct or what modifications I need.

Answer (score 0):

Generating the correct metadata can be complex.

The easiest way is to configure the RP manually.

Refer: [Node : Federating with ADFS via WS-Fed](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/search/label/Node.js).

Note this is WS-Fed but you can see how to configure SAML manually [here](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2015/12/identityserver-aspnet-mvc-application_16.html).